# Replay HTTP requests through chrome to view html response

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, jmeter

Is there any chrome extension available that sets up a proxy and allows you to replay HTTP(s) requests through it and view the html produced as it passes through?

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Repeater](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-repeater-https-live/jhojhhcdnopmbacgkggcgldbclfneefd?hl=en) seems to be something you're looking for
2. If 3rd-party standalone applications can be considered as well - [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) is probably the most advanced proxy
3. And given you have `jmeter` in your tags you can [record the traffic from Chrome (or any other browser)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) and replay it in JMeter, responses can be observed in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me Dmitry, essentially what I was looking is a decent HTML renderer. The one in the View Results Tree's not very good. Or at least it's not giving me back half of what I'd expect to see even though I can see that the results are good. I was hoping to be able to setup a proxy within chrome or firefox that would proxy the requests out and render the responses as if sent by the browser itself.